# Return type of function that will throw error if argument is not of specified type

Tags: typescript

What is the return type for a function that will guarantee the type of the argument, like type guard or throw an error if the type is different?

An example:

```
function throwIfNotStr(value: any): TYPE_HERE {
    if (typeof value === 'string') return;

    throw 'The arg. is not string!';
}
```

So usage like this:

```
function doWork(value: any) {
    throwIfNotStr(value);

    // After this line value is still of any type. But with the correct type, TS should guarantee that value is a string.

    console.log(value.indexOf('NO STR. TYPE CHECK AND NOT AUTOCOMPLETE HERE DUE TO ANY TYPE'))// Problem!    
}
```

An alternative solution is to use a type guard, however:

1. this requires to use of *redundant extra check* (`if` statement);
2. makes code *harder to read*;
3. and *violates the DRY* (do not repeat yourself) principle – since the need to throw an error with the same message again and again.

An example:

```
function throwIfNotStr(value: any): value is string {
    return typeof value === 'string';
}    

function doWork(value: any) {
    if (!throwIfNotStr(value)) throw 'EROROROROROR!';

    // …some work with correct type – value is a string.
}
function anotherDoWork(value: any) {
    if (!throwIfNotStr(value)) throw 'AGAIN_ERROR!!!';

    // …some work with correct type – value is a string.
}    
function againDoWork(value: any) {
    if (!throwIfNotStr(value)) throw 'ANOTHER_ERROR!!!';

    // …some work with correct type – value is a string.
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#assertion-functions

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe thank you very much! That's it, I've been looking for a few days, but somehow I missed `asserts`!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `asserts` keyword together with **type guard**, as proposed by @jonrsharpe (thanks!). Now all works as it should to be:

```
function throwIfNotStr(value: any): asserts value is string {
    if (typeof value === 'string') return;

    throw 'The arg. is not string!';
}

function doWork(value: any) {
    throwIfNotStr(value);

    // Success! After this line "value" is of a string type.

    console.log(value.indexOf('SomeText'));// Works!
}
```

Details - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#assertion-functions